# Why would I ever create a separate mutex/lock object?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am modifying some concurrent code at work and recently read through Java's docs on [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Given that every object has an intrinsic lock, why would I ever create a separate object for the purposes of controlling access to a particular item?

I recognize that there may be a use case where the item of interest is not a `malloc`'d `Object`, (`int` vs `Integer`) and therefore doesn't have an intrinsic lock but... assuming that we are concerned about synchronizing some `static Object`, is there anything to lose?

e.g.:

```java
public class main {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Integer foo = 10;
        
        synchronized(foo){
            foo ++;
        }
    }
}
```

If I wanted to update `foo` from multiple threads, synchronously, why wouldn't I just use the object that I want to modify? Is this less performant? I see lots of `synchronized(this)`, and separate instances where we may make a lock object for the purposes of synchronization:

```java
public class main {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Integer foo = 10; 
        Object fooLock = new Object();
        
        synchronized(fooLock){
            foo ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Why would I ever create `fooLock`, when I could instead use the object of actual interest? Is this actually discouraged (not idiomatic), or is there a practical reason not to do this?

I am thinking of doing the first approach (`synchronized(foo)`) for a `static` socket connection object, but it concerns me that I have not seen discussion of this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Anybody anywhere within the code running in the JVM can acquire a lock on `foo`, because it points to a globally-accessible instance (because `Integer.valueOf` is cached in the range at least -128..127). That means there could be liveness issues that you/they don't expect. OTOH, nobody else has access to `fooLock`.

Comment: You might want to review the [`AtomicInteger` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), because clearly there are reasons for needing atomicity even on lowly integers.

Comment: @AndyTurner What makes `foo` globally accessible in a way that `fooLock`  is protected?

Comment: `foo` isn't globally-accessible, the value it points to is. Note that you don't lock on variables, but on the value it points to.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah, I see. So by making a `final` lock object, we are preventing any modifications from being meaningful? I assume the implication here is that, if `foo` is `synchronized(fooLock)`, we are assuming `foo`'s value *is not* globally modifiable without prior acquisition of `fooLock`; but on the other hand, `fooLock` *will* be globally modifiable, but that issue would be moot?

Comment: @CaffeineDependent your example is a bit too contrived, because there is no point in synchronizing on a local variable that doesn't escape the thread. If it were a member/static variable, the point of making it `final` isn't so much to do with making it unassignable (although it does), but rather to do with guaranteeing the visibility of the non-null value after the constructor/static initialization has finished.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The use of `int` in this example was purely for illustrative purposes to communicate my point. The answers I acquire here will be abstracted to a more sophisticated implementation. I am using `AtomicLong/Bool`'s elsewhere, that is not the question at hand. (Though, I agree with your statement.)

Comment: It's not about the final, it's about the fact that there aren't multiple copies of Integer values below 128 ever. This means. if you lock on `10`, and use `10` anywhere else in the code, it's gonna be the same exact thing.

Comment: @JohannesH. Understood, I see the disconnect. Perhaps I need to provide a different example, though, I think I have my answer.

Comment: Generally, by using a private lock object, you're ensuring that only your code can synchronize on that object, which can make your code safer and easier to reason about.

Comment: @CaffeineDependent Yes, after reading your answers here, I do think that by using an integer in your example you introduced a couple of additional points that would be moot in a different example (that uses, for example, a simple POJO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a comment, not an answer to your question.

---

Your two examples are not equivalent. The second one prevents more than one thread* from entering the `synchronized` block at the same time, but the first one can allow many threads to be in the block at the same time.

That's because, in the first one, `synchronized(foo)` locks whichever `Integer` object the `foo` variable happens to refer to at a given moment in time, but the `foo++` statement reassigns `foo` so that it refers to a different object. Different threads could all be in the block at the same time, with each of them synchronized on a different object.

In the second example, `fooLock` is *effectively* immutable. It always refers to the same `Object` instance. Since every thread is trying to synchronize on the same object as every other thread, they will be forced to go through the block one at a time.

---

* Actually, both of your examples are complete programs that never create any new threads. In my comment, I'm *imagining* what would happen if the body of your `main(...)` function actually were in some other function that was called by many threads within some larger program.

Comment: Indeed, the example does not create any threads, or perform concurrency. I was trying to draw attention to the use of some object as both a lock and something that we are manipulating. Many of the comments for my original question are relating to the particular use of `Integer`, which is fair. 

I am going to mark your answer as "the answer", as I think yours and the other comments lead to an understanding.

Comment: @CaffeineDependent, My "answer" does not even begin to touch on the advantages of keeping a "lock object" private. Some of the comments on your question touch on that subject.

Answer (score 1):

So the immediate issue that your example causes is that your code uses immutable objects, updates cause the variable to point to a new object, and the whole locking scheme falls apart.

Now forget about updates, say you have code that synchronizes on the Integer 10, and that value doesn't change so we don't have the issue above. What if some other code in the codebase also synchronizes on the integer 10? Integers below a certain value get cached, so there is only one of each of them in a given JVM. If these two code paths get exercised concurrently in the same JVM then you can have the possibility of two otherwise unrelated pieces of code where one blocks the other for no good reason except they happen to use the same object to synchronize on.

When you reuse something that has another usage there is the risk that, even if it works perfectly well now, some change in the future to that other usage will impact the locking scheme. Keeping the lock as a dedicated object means there is no danger of having other reasons to change the object.

In a large application it is hard to keep everyone in the loop about what to lock and what not to, people may reuse pre-existing code in unexpected ways. If you use `synchronized` without specifying a lock then you get the monitor on the object, and any code accessing that object can acquire the lock. Declaring a dedicated object within the object instance to use as a lock makes it harder for other parts of the codebase to interfere with an object's usage of the lock.

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes a design decision. Even though each java object has an instrinsic monitor that one could use for synchronisation, by using a private object's monitor instead we effectively **encapsulate the class' synchronization policy**. This is considered a safer practice because external users of the class cannot acquire the monitor and therefore interfere with the class synchronization policy.

Other times this may be done to **improve performance** (especially in concurrent data structures). For example `ConcurrentHashMap` uses a technique called lock striping, using several different monitors (instead of the class intrinsic monitor) to guard disjoint parts of the underlying data structure and thereby decrease contention during data access.